# React redux is not changing routes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

Updating this question to use `connected-react-router` instead of `react-router-redux` since it is not compatible with `react-router` v4.

I can't seem to get my routing working when dispatching an action. I suspect it's because I'm using sagas which aren't being configured properly.

I have a saga:

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { push } from 'connected-react-router'

//...

yield call(push, '/dashboard')
```

The push function doesn't redirect the browser to the specified path despite the redux logs in webdev tools showing that the action was successfully dispatched.

The top level index.js file looks like:

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import rootSaga from './redux/sagas'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import App from './App'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import rootReducer from './redux/modules'
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { routerMiddleware, connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

const history = createBrowserHistory()
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store = createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  composeEnhancer(
    applyMiddleware(
      sagaMiddleware,
      routerMiddleware(history),
      logger
    )
  )
)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App history={history} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}

render()

registerServiceWorker()
```

The App.js file containing the root component has:

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        { routes }
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

What's missing from this setup to make it work?

Dependency versions:

```
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"connected-react-router": "^4.3.0"
```

Comment: just to note, that `react-router-redux@5.0.0-alphaXX` is working fine with `react-router@4.X.X`

Comment: @Simpleton I posted my solution. Dont know if it is correct or not but seems to work for me. Have you found any other solution mate?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `history`'s `push` method (which is an impure function), `connected-react-router`'s `push` is an ***action creator*** and its result (***action***) must be dispatched to trigger a navigation.
To do so in `redux-saga` you have to use `put`, not `call`.

`call` creates a ***call effect***.
When yielded, it simply executes given function with given arguments and returns a result. It is a good fit for (but not limited by) impure function calls (e.g. network request), by decoupling us from a direct execution of a function.

`put` creates a ***dispatch effect***.
When yielded, it dispatches passed in action object. Thus, decoupling your code only from a direct call of `dispatch`, not action creator (which should be pure by design).

So, in your case, the solution would look like:

```
yield put(push('/dashboard'))
```

*P.S: the same applies to `react-router-redux`'s `push`*

Answer (score 2):

you need to wire up the [router's middleware](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions), e.g.:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'

const sagaMw = createSagaMiddleware()
const routerMw = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
const middleware = applyMiddleware(sagaMw, routerMw, logger)
```

Comment: This config only works for v3 of react-router. For version 4 (as indicated above), that import results in `'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'`

Comment: Your comment lead me to notice that `react-router-redux` is not being maintained and is not compatible with react-router 4 so I've updated the details of the question.

Comment: does a direct call `push('/dashboard')` work by itself without Redux, e.g. in some dummy button's click handler? and/or when you dispatch some other function, is it executed, e.g. `yield call(console.log, 'test')`? if both work individually, you could try experimenting with different order of middlewares and if that won't work and no one else can figure it out, I would recommend using `redux-thunk` instead of sagas ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: One should inject history object during app initialization, so `createStore = (state, history) => {...}`. Thus, decoupling this file from particular history object type.

Comment: hey, I am using `react-router-redux` with the `react-router` v4 and It works really well. It says its in alpha, but it works perfectly on my project: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux

Answer (score 0):

> Sagas are implemented as Generator functions that yield objects to the
>   redux-saga middleware

So your Saga should export a *Generator* function:

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { push } from 'connected-react-router'

//...

export function* rootSaga() {
    return yield call(push, '/dashboard')
}
```

And `rootSaga` should be registered with the `sagaMiddleware`:

```
import { rootSaga } from './redux/sagas';
...
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
...
```

Reference: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work for me is to use `withRoter` (dont know if it is correct way or not):

```
export default withRouter(compose(withConnect)(App)); //wrapped in withRouter
```

Or

```
export default compose(
  withRouter,
  withConnect,
)(App);
```

And in redux-saga:

```
yield put(push('/newpage'));
```

I use react-boilerplate, https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate.
I don't know if it is correct or not but this way the route changes in url and I get to the new route. If i don't use `withRouter` the route changes in url and nothing more happens...
I found solution here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Would like to have someone opinion on that. Folks at https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate maybe?